# I would like to alter the way create-react-app builds my app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

So I would like to make `npm run build` to produce local runnable files.  Basically, I want it to build `index.js` with importing assets like `./static/js/chunk.js` instead of `/static/js/chunk.js`.  The client I am running this on does not have internet access so I want to serve the app from the file system.

Basically, I want to open index.html in the build folder with chrome and the app just work. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using simple node js and serve it as static is the best way because react router dom need url in the app.

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use("/static", express.static());

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend", "build", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(6000, () => console.log("Listening to port 6000"));
```

Next to node file index.js, or whatever you name it, make the folder called frontend. Inside it put your build from react so the node can serve index.html in port 6000